# How do I create this circular shape in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-canvas, android-jetpack-compose-canvas

I have a Pomodoro app and want to use this circular shape. This shape changes according to time value. Dots on the outside are not important, I want an inside and circular shape on my app. I used Jetpack Compose with drawArc and Canvas, but can't achieve it.

> I want something like this:

[image: circle design]

Here are my codes:

```
Canvas(modifier.offset(y = 10.dp)) {
    drawArc(
        color = inactiveBarColor,
        startAngle = 90f,      
        sweepAngle = 90f,       
        useCenter = false,
        size = Size(size.width.toFloat(), size.height.toFloat()),
        style = Stroke(strokeWidth.toPx(), cap = StrokeCap.Round)
   )
   drawArc(
        color = activeBarColor,
        startAngle = 0f,      
        sweepAngle = 90f,
        useCenter = false,
        size = Size(size.width.toFloat(), size.height.toFloat()),
        style = Stroke(strokeWidth.toPx(), cap = StrokeCap.Round)
   )
}
```

Values of angles are random, and just used for demonstrating

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can draw it like this. By changing values you can build exact clock shape. And you need to convert from time to angle for sweep angle in your code.

[image]

```
 @Preview
@Composable
private fun ClockArcSample() {
    Column {

        var sweepAngle by remember {
            mutableStateOf(90f)
        }

        Canvas(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(Color.Red)
                .aspectRatio(1f)
        ) {
            val canvasWidth = size.width
            val arcDiameter = canvasWidth * .55f

            drawCircle(
                color = Color.White,
                style = Stroke(canvasWidth * 0.04f),
                radius = canvasWidth * .35f
            )

            drawArc(
                color = Color.White,
                270f,
                sweepAngle,
                true,
                topLeft = Offset((canvasWidth - arcDiameter) / 2, (canvasWidth - arcDiameter) / 2),
                size = Size(arcDiameter, arcDiameter)
            )

            val strokeWidth = 2.dp.toPx()
            for (i in 0..360 step 6) {
                rotate(i.toFloat()) {
                    drawLine(
                        color = Color.White,
                        strokeWidth = strokeWidth,
                        start = Offset(
                            x = canvasWidth * 0.90f,
                            y = center.y
                        ),
                        end = Offset(
                            x = canvasWidth * 0.93f,
                            y = center.y
                        ),
                        cap = StrokeCap.Round
                    )
                }
            }
        }

        Slider(
            value = sweepAngle,
            onValueChange = { sweepAngle = it },
            valueRange = 0f..360f
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, it works fine, now it is time to implement this UI with logic

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, you need to convert time to sweep angle. Happy coding.